# Jython :reading multiple files using multiple threads

Tags: jython, grinder

i have a **jython script** using grinder reading values from **multiple files** using **multiple** **threads**.Threads are accessing a single value at a time and there is a **concurrency problem**.how to read multiple files with multiple threads without concurrency

Answer (score 0):

I originally wrote MTFileUtil so my Grinder scripts would have a tool to do stuff similar to what you are talking about.  The MT stands for "multi-thread".  You can use it to open multiple files, then read from those files randomly or sequentially.

The reader is thread-safe, so you should be able to access it from multiple threads.

See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mtFileUtil/

Comment: Thank you Travis.but is there an inbuilt function or property in grinder that automatically handles thread synchronisation or something which enables you to read files sequentially or randomly without having threading issues